# Preventing execution of unauthorised code

Tags: clojure

I'm currently writing an application that accepts a series of Clojure forms and when they are evaluated, the results get returned in a list

so for example the input would be

```
(data "abc" :identifier)
(data "gee" :identifier)
(content "def" :identifier [1 2 3 4 5])
```

The functions in the backend basically just turn these into Clojure maps, e.g.

```
(defn data [text id]
    {:text text :id id})
(defn content [text id cont]
    {:text text :id id :cont cont})
```

The trouble is, the way that I am processing the code at the moment is by accepting the input with `(-> input read-string eval)` and getting the contents accordingly. This is bad because anyone could just append a crafty `(System/exit 1)` to the input and shutdown the JVM

Is there any way of 'whitelisting' the Clojure forms that can be executed in this step and blacklisting all of the nasty stuff? Or am I being too naive to use Clojure forms as a data input mechanism?

Comment: Holy Bobby Tables!  There may be mechanisms for that, but you will need to trade off their convenience with the potential risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only have a fixed whitelist of allowable functions, you can easily roll your own here. Just have a map like `{'data data, 'content content}`, mapping symbols to allowed functions, and look up the first element of their form (which is a function call) in the map. If it's there, it maps straight to the function you want to call, and you can pass it the rest of their form as arguments.

Comment: make sure you bind *read-eval* to false to prevent the use of the read-eval macro `#(System/exit1)`

Comment: Ah this is what I needed, thanks for the tip! I also made use of the ```clojail/safe-read``` function to read in the forms

Comment: That's an important step (either solution is fine), and it's one many people forget - even me, and I'm the one who added `safe-read` to clojail!

Answer (score 6):

check out [Clojail](https://github.com/flatland/clojail) and its great [video from the 2011 Clojure Conj](http://lanyrd.com/2011/clojure-conj/shhfb/)!

you can interact with it on #clojure on irc.freenode.net and try to break through it if you would like :) goes by the handle lazybot. it is also used on [4clojure.org](http://www.4clojure.com/problems)

Comment: Cool, just been looking into this. I've gone with amalloy's solution as it's more suitable for what I needed, but I'm using the ```safe-read``` function in Clojail too.